# difference between SQL Server 32 and 64 bit

Tags: sql-server

What exactly is the difference between SQL Server 32 bit and SQL Server 64 bit?

If I am going to install SQL Server on a of 32 bit version of Windows, then which version of SQL Server to choose?

Comment: try 64-bit and tell us if you suceed

Comment: On a 32bit Windows (who would use that for a Server installation today?) you can only install 32bit programsn.

Comment: Thanks..I am not an admin..just asked this question to update my knowledge

Comment: You would need to [install windows 32 bit twice](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/efcd4783-e948-4f85-9659-7a6e9139a931/upgrading-from-windows-7-32bit-to-64bit) to make 64 bit. (j/k)

Comment: It's 2014. Why are you running a 32-bit version of Windows anywhere? This is why we can't have nicer things all around - Microsoft still wastes time building, testing and shipping 32-bit versions of software  like SQL Server because you people won't use the right operating system...

Comment: sIR,GOT A GOOD SITE http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/32-bit-and-64-bit-explained.htm

Comment: I am a developer,the decision of selecting os has to come from It head or concerned people..The question over here is only as a part of my understanding abou the os and application

Comment: If your "It head or concerned people" are choosing a 32-bit OS for you, somebody should be thwapping their wrists with a ruler.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the cheap comment but common sense can answer your Q.

However if you are addressing to the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit Systems in general, this has to do with the length of bits of each word used be CPU registry:

- 32-bits use 32bits word
- 64ibits use 64bits word

Thus if a System is 32-bit we cant install a 64-bit program cause CPU could not "translate" the words (bytes)

However in 64-bit systems we can use 32bit programs cause (simplified) each 32-bit word fits in the 64-bit buffered registry

Comment: THANKS..I GOT AN EXPLANATION  http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/32-bit-and-64-bit-explained.htm